# Interactive renderplot graph with multidimensional dataset

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to run an interactive rshiny plot. I have this output: 
[image: shiny output in browser]

I want to be able to subset and plot by country, by scenario, by variable, by year (4 selections). I also want to be able to add value points by year and not have the whole plot by year done immediately.
I am only able to subset by country. My scenario and variable dropdowns are not reactive. And it plots all variables with all scenarios although I want one variable plot by one scenario and one country

How can I make my graph interactive?

```
library(reshape2)
library(lattice)
library(plyr)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(abind)
library(ggplot2)

 ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Comparing Trend and PP policies by MDGs and funding"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Country"),choices=unique(dmiubf$country), selected = ""),
      selectInput("Senario","Show senario:", choices = unique(dmiubf$scn)),
      selectInput("var","Show senario:", choices = unique(dmiubf$var)),
      selectInput("year","Show vertical line in year(s):", choices = unique(dmiubf$year),multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("chart")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  cr <- reactive({
    a = dmiubf[dmiubf$var==input$var, dmiubf$scn==input$senario]<-dmiubf[dmiubf[,"country"]=="Costa Rica",input$senario]<-"base"
    dmiubf
  })

  output$chart <- renderPlot({
    req(input$radio)
    if (input$radio==c("Costa Rica")) {
      plot0<-ggplot(data=cr()) + geom_point(aes(x=year,y=pcn, fill=scn),
                                            size = 6)
      print(plot0)
      }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you include a small example of your `dmiubf` dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing your app, but without knowing how the input data looks like, its a bit hard. So i created a random dummy dataset. Therefore it is not always showing a plot, as no data is left after the filtering process.

But as a starting point I think this should help you:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dmiubf <- data.frame(
  country=c(rep("Costa Rica",8), rep("England",8), rep("Austria",8), rep("Latvia",8)),
  scn = rep(c("base","high","low","extra"),8),
  year = sample(c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001), 32, replace = T),
  var = sample(c(1,2,3,4), 32, replace = T),
  pcn = sample(c(10,20,30,40), 32, replace = T)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Comparing Trend and PP policies by MDGs and funding"),  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Country"),choices= as.character(unique(dmiubf$country)), selected = ""),
      selectInput("Senario","Show senario:", choices = as.character(unique(dmiubf$scn))),
      selectInput("var","Show senario:", choices = sort(unique(dmiubf$var))),
      selectInput("year","Show vertical line in year(s):", choices = sort(unique(dmiubf$year)), multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("chart")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  cr <- reactive({
    a <- dmiubf[as.character(dmiubf$country)==input$radio & 
                  dmiubf$var %in% as.numeric(input$var) & 
                  dmiubf$year %in% as.numeric(input$year) & 
                  as.character(dmiubf$scn)==input$Senario
                ,]
    a
  })

  output$chart <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(nrow(cr())!=0, "No Data to plot")
    )
    ggplot(data=cr()) + geom_point(aes(x=year, y=pcn, fill=scn), size = 6)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```